# Is there a noun to describe the status of something being "indoor" or "outdoor"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm not a native English speaker, and I'm searching for a noun (that may not exist?) that would help me describe if something is happening  "indoors" or "outdoors".

For example, instead of asking, "Is this activity indoor or outdoor?" I would like to ask, "What is the xxx of this activity?"

Indoorness, outdoorness, etc.,  don't seem to exist. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: One is tempted to coin *alfrescosity.*

Comment: @BrianDonovan An alternative coinage might be _murality_ as in _extra mural_ and _intra mural_ but I don't think anyone would know wht it meant;-)

Comment: @BrianDonovan - I would say "doorishness".

Comment: 'What is the xxx of this activity?' is unlikely to be any shorter than 'Is this activity indoors or outdoors?' (unless *xxx* turns out to be a very short word). What would be the benefit of using such a word, if it existed?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not aware of a noun for this. In practice, I would guess and ask if I’m correct: “Will this dinner be indoors?” Since there are only two options, this works well enough. Words get created to fill a need, and this need isn’t common enough to bother.

Answer (score -1):

The best preposition that you could use in this scenario is *location*. For example, you could say "What is the *location* of this activity?", or to better put it for conversational language, "Where is this activity going to be located?". If it is understood that you know the literal location of it, then English speakers will probably understand that you mean indoors versus outdoors.

Comment: The reply "Five-a-side football will take place at the Joshi Sports Complex" still does not reveal the information. Best to ask a more specific question.

Comment: That's also true.

Comment: No, far too hypernymic to be a valid answer.